# Black Screen agora remote view flutter

Tags: flutter, live-streaming, agora.io

I am trying to implement the flutter Agora SDK Livestream with agora and I'm getting a black screen on remote view, local view works fine.

Please what am I doing wrongly?

What I tried:

- double-check if all permissions are enabled
- recreate a new application In agora.io
- switch devices
- check internet connectivity

This is the code for the implementation:

```
void initEngine() async {
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(agoraKey);

    addListeners();
    _engine.enableVideo();
    _engine.startPreview();
    _engine.enableAudio();

    _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    print(widget.isBroadcaster);
    if (("${widget.userData.uid}${widget.userData.name}" == widget.channeId)) {
      _engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
      print('broadcaster');
    } else {
      _engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Audience);
      print('audience');
    }

    _joinChannel();
  }

  _renderVideo(
    user,
    isScreenSharing,
  ) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      child: "${user.uid}${user.name}" == widget.channeId
          ? isScreenSharing
              ? kIsWeb
                  ? const RtcLocalView.SurfaceView.screenShare()
                  : const RtcLocalView.TextureView.screenShare()
              : const RtcLocalView.SurfaceView(
                  zOrderMediaOverlay: true,
                  zOrderOnTop: true,
                )
          : isScreenSharing
              ? kIsWeb
                  ? const RtcLocalView.SurfaceView.screenShare()
                  : const RtcLocalView.TextureView.screenShare()
              : isRendered
                  ? RtcRemoteView.TextureView(
                      uid: _remoteUids[0],
                      channelId: widget.channeId,
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'No Video',
                        style: GoogleFonts.balooPaaji2(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
    );
  }

  void addListeners() {
    _engine.setEventHandler(RtcEngineEventHandler(
      joinChannelSuccess: (channel, uid, elapsed) async {
        debugPrint('joinChannelSuccess $channel $uid $elapsed');
        print(
            'joinChannelSuccess ======================================================> $uid');
      },
      leaveChannel: (stats) {
        debugPrint('leaveChannel $stats');
        setState(() {
          _remoteUids.clear();
        });
      },
      userJoined: (uid, elapsed) {
        debugPrint('userJoined $uid $elapsed');
        setState(() {
          print('userJoined=====================>:$_remoteUids');
          _remoteUids.add(uid);
          setState(() {
            isRendered = true;
          });
          print('=======>====>$_remoteUids');
        });
      },
      userOffline: (uid, reason) {
        debugPrint('userOffline=====================> $uid $reason');
        setState(() {
          _remoteUids.remove(uid);
        });
      },
      userMuteAudio: (uid, muted) {
        debugPrint('userMuteAudio $uid $muted');
      },
      userMuteVideo: (uid, muted) {
        debugPrint('userMuteVideo $uid $muted');
      },
      userEnableVideo: (uid, enabled) {
        debugPrint('userEnableVideo $uid $enabled');
      },
      error: (error) {
        debugPrint('error $error');
      },
    ));
    print('=====.$_remoteUids========');
  }

  void _joinChannel() async {
    //leave the current channel

    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
      await _engine.joinChannel(
          tempToken, 'testing_channel', widget.channeId, 0);
      debugPrint('joinChannelWithUserAccount ${widget.channeId} ');
    } else {
      await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
      await _engine.joinChannel(
          tempToken, 'testing_channel', widget.channeId, 0);
      debugPrint('joinChannelWithUserAccount ${widget.channeId} ');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **Uid** in Rtc remote view is the same with the user went live and the user joined to live

**RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(
uid: ,
channelId:,
)**